Revision on solutions regarding combinations of bit strings
How many bit strings of length 65 are there such that the bit string contains exactly twenty-five 0s, additionally, the bit string corresponding to the first eight positions must have exactly two 1s and the bit string corresponding to the last thirty-seven positions must not contain the string 1000110 as a substring.
This is how I've approached the problem.
Since in the first 8 positions we have exactly 2 ones:
$\binom{8}{2}$
We have 65-8-37 = 20 middle positions. Since we have no constraint here it would mean $2^{20}$?
Lastly I account for each substring in the last 37 positions (accounting for overlaps) and make the product with either $2^{n}$ (where n is basically the length of substring occurences) or instead accounting for the remaining positions available (65-first 8 positions - positions occupied by substrings).
So the two possible results I got are
$\binom{8}{2}*[\binom{57}{38}-\binom{31}{1}*\binom{50}{35}-\binom{26}{1}*\binom{45}{33}-\binom{25}{2}*\binom{36}{32}-\binom{21}{1}*\binom{40}{31}-\binom{20}{2}*\binom{38}{30}-\binom{17}{3}*\binom{36}{29}]$
$\binom{8}{2}*[\binom{57}{38}-\binom{31}{1}*2^{30}-\binom{26}{1}*2^{25}-\binom{25}{2}*2^{23}-\binom{21}{1}*2^{20}-\binom{20}{2}*2^{18}-\binom{17}{3}*2^{14}]$
I am afraid both are incorrect I would like revision and help on this kind of problem.
Edit
This would be the full solution I came up with:
$\binom{8}{6} * 2^{57} - [\binom{31}{1}*\binom{50}{15}-\binom{26}{1}*\binom{45}{12}-\binom{25}{2}*\binom{43}{11}+\binom{21}{1}*\binom{40}{9}+2*\binom{20}{2}*\binom{38}{8}+\binom{19}{3}*\binom{36}{7}-\binom{16}{1}*\binom{35}{6}-3*\binom{15}{2}*\binom{33}{5}-3*\binom{14}{3}*\binom{31}{4}-\binom{13}{4}*\binom{29}{3}+\binom{11}{1}*\binom{30}{3}+4*\binom{10}{2}*\binom{28}{2}+3*\binom{9}{3}*\binom{26}{1}+4*\binom{8}{4}-\binom{6}{1}]$

There is a constraint on the middle positions, since all told there are supposed to be $25$ zeroes.

@GerryMyerson yes I've accounted for the constraint on the middle positions in the full solution right after the edit.
