Revision on solution regarding combinations of a ternary string
A ternary string is a sequence of digits, where each digit is 0, 1, or 2. How many ternary strings of length 56 are there such that the string corresponding to the first twenty positions has exactly seven 0s and three 1s, and the string corresponding to the last twenty-seven positions contains the substring 120012?
This is how I've approached the problem.
Since in the first 20 positions we have exactly 7 zeros and 3 ones:
$\binom{20}{7}*\binom{13}{3}$
We have 56-20-27 = 9 middle positions. Since we have no constraint here it would mean $3^{9}$?
Lastly I account for each substring in the last 27 positions (accounting for overlaps) and make the product with $3^{n}$ (where n is basically the length of substring occurences).
So the result I got is
$\binom{20}{7}*\binom{13}{3}*3^{9}*[\binom{22}{1}*3^{21}-\binom{18}{1}*3^{17}-\binom{17}{2}*3^{15}+\binom{14}{1}*3^{13}+\binom{13}{2}*3^{11}+\binom{12}{3}*3^{9}]$
I am afraid this is incorrect and so I would like revision and help on this kind of problem.

The first two parts look good, the third part with PIE,
the principle of inclusion and exclusion, needs to be revised.
We are looking for the number of occurrences of the ternary substring $120012$ in a ternary string of length $27$. We have to consider multiple occurrences and the kinds of overlapping as in
\begin{align*}
1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012\qquad1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012\qquad1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012\qquad\cdots
\end{align*}
Since we have to cope with many different cases it is good to have some bookkeeping. We start with some kind of systematic notation which is appropriate for the small cases where we consider (at least) one, two or three occurrences of the wanted substring $120012$.
$\mathbb{120012}$ once: We count the number of occurrences of the substring $120012$ in the string of length $27$. We also write symbolically the way it occurs and its length, which is helpful especially for the more complicated cases which follows.
\begin{align*}
&(120012\ (6))\\
\\
&\binom{27-1\cdot 6 +1}{1}\color{blue}{=\binom{22}{1}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
$120012$ twice:
\begin{align*}
&(1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012\ (10)\\
&\quad|\ 120012, 120012\ (12))\\
\\
&\binom{27-10 +1}{1}+\binom{27-2\cdot 6+2}{2}\color{blue}{=\binom{18}{1}+\binom{17}{2}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
$120012$ thrice:
\begin{align*}
&(1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012\ (14)\\
&\quad|\ 1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012, 120012\ (16)\\
&\quad|\ 120012, 120012, 120012\ (18))\\
\\
&\binom{27-14 +1}{1}+\frac{2!}{1!1!}\binom{27-10-6+2}{2}+\binom{27-3\cdot 6+3}{3}\\
&\quad\color{blue}{=\binom{14}{1}+2\binom{13}{2}+\binom{12}{3}}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
Note the factor $\frac{2!}{1!1!}=2$ which respects the order of the two different substrings $1200120012$ and $120012$. Whenever there are different substrings to consider we have to take the order of the different substrings into account.
The following observations indicate patterns we may take into consideration. These patterns can be used to check that all cases are considered.

The weights of the binomial coefficients are $1$ in (1), $1, 1$ in (2) and $1, 2, 1$ in (3). This looks like the beginning of Pascal's triangle.

The upper indices of the binomial indices decrease by one, the lower indices start with one and increase by one.

The upper indices of the left-most binomial coefficients $22, 18. 14$ form an arithmetic progression with common difference $d=-4$.


We will see these patterns are also valid in the following cases.
$120012$ four times:
In order to better see that we cover all different cases we also use a representation via integer partitions
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{4}\qquad\qquad\qquad(1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012\ (18)\\
&\mathbb{3+1}\ \ \qquad\quad\qquad|\ 1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012, 120012\ (20)\\
&\mathbb{2+2}\ \ \qquad\quad\qquad|\ 1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012, 1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012\ (20)\\
&\mathbb{2+1+1}\ \ \,\quad\qquad|\ 1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012, 120012, 120012\ (22)\\
&\mathbb{1+1+1+1}\quad\quad|\ 120012, 120012, 120012, 120012\ (24))\\
\\
&\binom{27-18+1}{1}+\frac{2!}{1!1!}\binom{27-14-6+2}{2}+\binom{27-2\cdot 10+2}{2}\\
&\qquad+\frac{3!}{1!2!}\binom{27-10-2\cdot 6+3}{3}+\binom{27-4\cdot 6+4}{4}\\
&\quad\color{blue}{=\binom{10}{1}+3\binom{9}{2}+3\binom{8}{3}+\binom{7}{4}}\tag{4}
\end{align*}
$120012$ five times:
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{5}\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad(1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012\ (22)\\
&\mathbb{4+1}\ \ \quad\quad\qquad\qquad|\ 1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012, 120012\ (24)\\
&\mathbb{3+2}\ \ \qquad\quad\quad\qquad|\ 1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012, 1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012\ (24)\\
&\mathbb{3+1+1}\ \ \,\quad\quad\qquad|\ 1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012, 120012, 120012\ (26)\\
&\mathbb{2+2+1}\ \ \,\quad\quad\qquad|\ 1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012, 1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012, 120012\ (26)\\
&\mathbb{2+1+1+1}\quad\quad\ \ \ \,|\ \ (28)\\
&\mathbb{1+1+1+1+1}\quad\,|\ \ (30))\\
\\
&\binom{27-22+1}{1}+\frac{2!}{1!1!}\binom{27-18-6+2}{2}+\frac{2!}{1!1!}\binom{27-14-10+2}{2}\\
&\qquad+\frac{3!}{1!2!}\binom{27-14-2\cdot 6+3}{3}+\frac{3!}{2!1!}\binom{27-2\cdot 10-6+3}{3}\\
&\quad\color{blue}{=\binom{6}{1}+4\binom{5}{2}+6\binom{4}{3}}\tag{5}
\end{align*}
Since we consider a ternary string of length $27$ the last do cases do not contribute.
$120012$ six times:
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{6}\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad(1200{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}00{\color{blue}{\mathbb{12}}}0012\ (26))\\
\\
&\binom{27-26+1}{1}\color{blue}{=\binom{2}{1}}\tag{6}
\end{align*}
We observe only one case is relevant as all the other cases have length greater than $27$.

If you combine (1) to (6) following PIE and multiply them by powers of $3$ to fill the remaining digits of the entire string, you get the desired number of occurrences as
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{\binom{22}{1}3^{21}-\left(\binom{18}{1}3^{17}+\binom{17}{2}3^{15}\right)}\\
&\quad\color{blue}{+\left(\binom{14}{1}3^{13}+2\binom{13}{2}3^{11}+\binom{12}{3}3^9\right)}\\
&\quad\color{blue}{-\left(\binom{10}{1}3^9+3\binom{9}{2}3^7+3\binom{8}{3}3^5+\binom{7}{4}3^3\right)}\\
&\quad\color{blue}{+\left(\binom{6}{1}3^5+4\binom{5}{2}3^3+6\binom{4}{3}3\right)}\\
&\quad\color{blue}{-\binom{2}{1} 3}\\
&=\color{blue}{225\,905\,609\,703}
\end{align*}


So I was just missing 120012 four times, five times and six times. Correct? Why we subtract for 120012 twice, four times and six times while in the other cases we add?

@zaxunobi: Yes, this is correct. Here we apply PIE, the principle of inclusion, exclusion. This means we have to compensate overcounting in both directions. Therefore we alternatively subtract and add.

I understand! Is there a formula to find the factor that respects the order of different substrings? Or should I simply proceed with a brute force, basically trying all possible combinations? Especially in cases such as four times, five times and six times.

By the way, I have a very similar question if you want to check it out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4962393/combinations-for-a-ternary-string-with-constraints

@zaxunobi: I don't think that there is a general formula available as it heavily depends on the different ways of overlapping depending on the kind of substrings which can occur. A higher level approach is the Goulden Jackson Cluster method which I have provided as answer to another question from you.

Let's say we change a small part of the problem ."..and the string corresponding to the last twenty-seven positions does NOT contain the substring 120012". How would it change your solution?

@zaxunobi: What do you think?

I think I would need to subtract rather than adding but I am not sure how exactly.

@zaxunobi: The number of ternary strings of length $27$ is $3^{27}$. From this number we have to subtract the number stated in the answer.

Thanks! If you want to check out another problem very similar to this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4955656/revision-on-solutions-regarding-combinations-of-bit-strings

Just to clarify, the final solution would be $\binom{20}{7}*\binom{13}{3}3^{9}$ multiplied by your answer or $\binom{20}{7}\binom{13}{3}$ multiplied by your answer? I am uncertain wether the middle positions need to be specified or not.

@zaxunobi: Since the question asks for the number of ternary strings of length $56$, we also have to consider that there are $3^9$ different cases in the middle part of the valid strings.

We can calculate the number of valid strings using the Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method. This is a technique which implicitly encodes the PIE principle, so that we do not have to consider each of the different cases explicitly. We consider the set of words of length $n\geq 0$ built from the alphabet $\mathcal{V}=\{0,1,2\}$ and the set $$B=\{120012\}$$ of bad words, which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for. We derive a generating function $B(z)$ with the coefficient of $z^n$ being  the number of wanted words of length $n$. According to the paper (p.7) the generating function $B(z)$  is
\begin{align*}
B(z)=\frac{1}{1-dz-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=3$, the size of the alphabet and $\mathcal{C}$ is the weight-numerator of bad words with
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[120012])\tag{4}
\end{align*}
Since we are looking for the number of words which do contain the string $120012$ the wanted generating function is given as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{1-3z}-B(z)}\tag{5}
\end{align*}
We calculate according to the paper
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[120012])&=-z^6-z^4\cdot\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[120012])\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad 1200{\color{blue}{\underline{12}}}0012\\
\end{align*}
The additional term on the right-hand side takes into account overlaps, which are indicated by the blue letters of the overlapping bad words in the line below. This is in fact an application of the inclusion-exclusion principle in terms of generating functions. It follows from (3) and (4)
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=-\frac{z^6}{1+z^4}\tag{6}
\end{align*}
We obtain from (3) and (6)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{B(z)}&=\frac{1}{1-dz-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-3z+\frac{z^6}{1+z^4}}\\
&=\color{blue}{\frac{1+z^4}{1-3z+z^4-3z^5+z^6}}\tag{7}\\
\end{align*}

We derive a generating function for the wanted words from (3) and (7) as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{1-3z}-B(z)}
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1-3z}-\frac{1+z^4}{1-3z+z^4-3z^5+z^6}}\\
&=z^6+6z^7+27z^8+108z^9+404z^{10}\\
&\qquad+\cdots\color{blue}{+225\,905\,609\,703 z^{27}}+\cdots
\end{align*}
where the last line was calculated with some help of WolframAlpha. We see the coefficient of $z^{27}$ coincides with the result from my other answer.

