Combinations for a ternary string with constraints
A ternary string is a sequence of digits, where each digit is 0, 1, or 2. How many ternary strings of length 70 are there such that the string contains exactly fifteen 0s and thirteen 2s, in addition the string corresponding to the first twenty positions has exactly five 0s and twelve 1s, and the string corresponding to the last twenty-nine positions contains the string 1021102 as a substring?
The problem needs to be solved with the principle of inclusion and exclusion and I will express the combinations as binomial coefficients.
Please note that I am going to disregard for the moment the overall constraint:

"such that the string contains exactly fifteen 0s and thirteen 2s"

So for first 20 positions: $\binom{20}{5}*\binom{15}{12}$
For the middle positions: 70-20-29 = 21, it would be $3^{21}$
For the last 29 positions I basically counted the occurrences of the substring (taking in account also overlaps and repetitions) and the result is:
$\binom{23}{1}*3^{22}-\binom{19}{1}*3^{18}-\binom{17}{2}*3^{15}+\binom{13}{2}*3^{11}+\binom{13}{2}*3^{11}+\binom{11}{3}*3^{8}-\binom{11}{1}*3^{10}-3*\binom{7}{3}*3^{4}-3*\binom{9}{2}*3^{7}-\binom{5}{4}*3^{1}+\binom{7}{1}*3^{6}+6*\binom{3}{3}*3^{0}+4*\binom{5}{2}*3^{3}-\binom{8}{1}*3^{7}$
The above solution accounts for the substring present from 1 to six times and as I said before I have disregard the overall constraint.
What I would like to ask you if this is correct and then how I would to apply the overall constraint to get the final result. Thank you.

Edit: now I am going to solve the problem also with the overall constraint. To count the numbers of zeros and ones for the remaining digits between the middle positions and last positions I thought I could do something like showed below:
For substring 1021102:
29 - 7 + 1 = 23 (removing from the last 29 positions the length of the substring)
70 - 20 - 7 = 43 (removing from the overall length the first 20 positions and the length of the substring)
15 - 5 - 2 = 8 (removing from the 15 zeros, 5 zeros of the first 20 positions and 2 zeros of the substring)
42 - 12 - 3 = 27 (removing from the 42 ones, 12 ones of the first 20 positions and 3 ones of the substring)
So, in this case we would have: $\binom{23}{1}*\binom{43}{8}*\binom{35}{27}$
For substring 1021102 1021102:
29 - 14 + 2 = 17
70 - 20 - 14 = 36
15 - 5 - 4 = 6
42 - 12 - 6 = 24
So, in this case we would have: $\binom{17}{2}*\binom{36}{6}*\binom{30}{24}$
And so on...
But since I am not sure about the validity of this approach and calculations I would kindly ask for a revision. Thank you.

Since the string contains exactly $15$ zeroes and $13$ twos, you are not free to select the middle $21$ positions in any way you like since you could select too many zeroes or too many twos.

@N.F.Taussig please check the edited question and tell me if now it's correct.

The first $20$ positions contain five zeroes and three twos, leaving $10$ zeroes and $10$ twos in the remainder of the string.  The seven-character string $1021102$ contains two zeroes and two twos.  The number of times that string appears determines the number of zeroes and twos that can appear in the remainder of the string.  I think you need to use the generalized Inclusion-Exclusion Principle since you need to consider cases depending on the exact number of appearances of the string.

@N.F.Taussig Isn't exactly what I did? Instead of zeros and two, I counted zeros and ones.

After looking at your work when I am fully alert, it looks sound.
